# How can I set semantic versioning for a Go project and what are commands to set the version?

Tags: go, semantic-versioning, glide-golang

How can I set semantic versioning  for Go project and what are commands to set the version?

Comment: Why the question is tagged `glide-golang`? Are you really using Glide this days? Is the question really about [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [go.dev](https://go.dev/doc/) website has some information about this.

The ["Module version numbering"](https://go.dev/doc/modules/version-numbers) doc page has information about the versioning standards, and mentions:

> If you’re developing modules for others to use, you apply a version number when you publish the module, tagging the module in its repository. For more, see **Publishing a module**.

The ["Publishing a module"](https://go.dev/doc/modules/publishing) doc page outlines the steps for publishing your module, including how to set the version number in steps 4 and 5:

> 4. Tag the project with a new version number using the git tag command.
>
> For the version number, use a number that signals to users the nature of changes in this release. For more, see **Module version numbering**.
>
> ```
> git commit -m "mymodule: changes for v0.1.0"
> git tag v0.1.0
> ```
>
> 5. Push the new tag to the origin repository.
>
> ```
> git push origin v0.1.0
> ```

Comment: but this only applies for modules what if we want to have version for hole project?

Comment: @MayurKadam "Project" is not a specific thing in Go, so I'm not sure what to tell you about it.

Comment: okk is there in file where we can get current modules semantic version and set the version

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications is this the correct way to set version for golang applications

Comment: @MayurKadam That's showing you how to set the value of a variable in your program with the build command. The fact that the variable is called "version" has no special significance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about now. The idea of a "version" is very abstract and could mean anything unless you provide context. In the context of Go tools, the only versions are those of modules, which I explained in my answer.